# Moving text field position on keyboard show in Lua for Android

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk

I am using the SDK "Corona" to develop Android applications in Lua.

I was wondering if you could all assist me in the following problem I have been experiencing. I am in the process of designing an app with text fields towards the bottom of the screen, but I would like the text fields to change position once touched, so that the keyboard does not overlap them when it pops up.

As such, I created a listener to execute code which changes the Y position of 2 fields when either one is touched, but for some odd reason, the code is not working. If I place the code in a button event listener however, it seems to work fine. Please refer to my code:

```
----------------email textbox -------------

local textField = native.newTextField( display.contentCenterX, display.contentCenterY + 60, 200, 40 )
textField.placeholder = "Email"
textField.isEditable = true

 --function to handle events
local function touchListener( event )

      textField.y = display.contentCenterY - 100
      textField2.y = display.contentCenterY - 50

end


textField:addEventListener( "touch", touchListener )
```

I thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Perhaps you should show us the code that is not working, rather then the code that does work?

Comment: @Frozire I apologise, amended as requested.

Comment: the listener `userInput` is only triggered by text input, you are aware of this right? So the text fields will not be moving position until user input text into a text field.

Comment: @Frozire I used textField:addEventListener( "touch", touchListener ) instead, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: And you are sure there is consistency between the function you define in the parameters of addEventListener and the function you defined? If yes, I will need more code to solve the problem - perhaps uploading your code somewhere allowing me to view the full code would be beneficial.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58123/discussion-between-frozire-and-kya-suleyman).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm correct, since textFields are a native object (and not a display object), they do not handle "touch" event.
As such you will need to use the "userInput" event to trigger the move of the textField.

Here is an example of the listener I have used in the past for this case (without the code to move around):

```
local function fctFieldListener(oEvent)
    local oTextField = oEvent.target

    if "began" == oEvent.phase then
        -- Move the input up if at the bottom
    elseif "editing" == oEvent.phase then

    elseif "submitted" == oEvent.phase then
        native.setKeyboardFocus( nil )
    elseif "ended" == oEvent.phase then
        -- Move the input back at his original place if adjusted
    end
end
```

And you add it to the textfield like this:

```
oTextField:addEventListener( 'userInput', fctFieldListener )
```

Also, I highly recommend that you put your native.newTextField in a specific display group that you will be moving around, instead of moving around the textField itself, makes things a lot easier.